# Run a string from var that is inside an array with other var to a function and display the results

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to understand how to run all var from an array into the same function and then log the results.  I have coded the function correctly, and will add all the letters after I understand how to load the whole array to the function without having to call each element.  i think i should use .forEach().  The top section of the code is working functions.  The bottom is my unsuccessful attempt to use .forEach().

```
const name1 = 'bill';
const name2 = 'matt';
const name3 = 'mike';
const name4 = 'joe';

const nameGroup = [name1, name2, name3, name4]


const findNameVal = (name) => {
  let nameSum = 0;
  let cardCheck = name;
    for (let i=0; i < cardCheck.length; i++) {
        if (name1.charAt(i) === 'a') {
             nameSum += 1; 
    } else if (name1.charAt(i)=== 'b') {
         nameSum += 2;
    } else if (name1.charAt(i)=== 'i') {
         nameSum += 9;
    } else if (name1.charAt(i)=== 'l') {
         nameSum += 12;
    } 
} return nameSum;
}
console.log(`The name is: ${name1} and the numerical value is ${findNameVal(name1)}`);



//attempt to use .forEach

  nameGroup.forEach(function(element) {
    let nameSum = 0;
    let cardCheck = name;
      for (let i=0; i < cardCheck.length; i++) {
          if (name1.charAt(i) === 'a') {
               nameSum += 1; 
      } else if (name1.charAt(i)=== 'b') {
           nameSum += 2;
      } else if (name1.charAt(i)=== 'i') {
           nameSum += 9;
      } else if (name1.charAt(i)=== 'l') {
           nameSum += 12;
      } 
  } return nameSum;
  }
  );
```

Comment: The `forEach` callback has `element` as param, which can be used to access the current element of `nameGroup`, yet your callback isn't using it at all. Replace `name1` with `element`, I guess? Live code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/12q93mxn/

Comment: for the .foreach()part of my code it says name is undefined. after change name1 to element the same, name is undefined

Comment: Did you look at the fiddle? I fixed your `fineNameVal` because it wasn't using the `name` parameter, instead it was hardcoded to use `name1`. Then I added a `forEach` example loop that logs each name and nameVal to the console.

Comment: Im using visual studio code with .js.  How to look at the fiddle?

Comment: Just click the link in my first comment

Answer (score 0):

You have your count function ready, all you need to do is call it for every element of the array. That would be:

```
namesGroup.forEach(function(name) {
  console.log(`The name is: ${name} and the numerical value is ${findNameVal(name)}`);
});
```

forEach runs a code block for every element of an array, `return` does not serve a purpose in its callback function.

Edit: Also, as the comment from @Chris G stated, your top function is not correct for any other case apart from name1.